# state parameter value is mixed with url in UI-Router in angularjs when refresh is clicked

Tags: angularjs, url, path, angular-ui-router, match

I am trying to creating web page to perform on edit actions in both in parent(first.edit) and child(second.edit) states. 
I sending related state parameters through URL, those are captured by using regex patterns.

When I click on  ui-sref="**home.first.edit({firstId:10})**" link the controller receiving state parameter **firstId** correctly i.e **10**.

When I click on ui-sref="**home.first.second.edit({firstId:10,secondId:20}**)" link or refresh the the state the controller receiving in correct value for **firstId** i.e **10/second/20**.
and it is moving to **parent state(home.first)**

This is my js file

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
  'ui.router'
])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Here are the `states`:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '',
  views: {
    'home_view': {
      templateUrl: 'index.html',
      controller: 'homeController'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.first', {
  url: "/first",
   params:{
    firstId:null
    },
  views: {
    'home_view': {
      templateUrl: "first.html",
      controller: 'firstCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.first.edit', {
      url: "/{firstId:[0-9]+}/edit",
      views: {
        'first_view': {
          templateUrl: "/edit_first.html",
          controller: 'firstCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
.state('home.first.second', {
    url: "/second",
    params:{
    secondId:null
    }
    views: {
      'first_view': {
        templateUrl: "/second.html",
        controller: 'secondCtrl'
      }

    }
  })
.state('home.first.second.edit', {
    url: "/{secondId:[0-9]+}/edit",
    views: {
      'second_view': {
        templateUrl: "/views/testplan/projects/edit_second.html",
        controller: 'secondCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is the rest of the code with `controller` definition

```
  .controller(
    'homeController',
    function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
      //  console.log($stateParams.firstId);
    }
  )
  .controller(
    'firstCtrl',
    function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
      console.log($stateParams.firstId);
    }
  )
  .controller(
    'secondCtrl',
    function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
      console.log($stateParams.secondId);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4O8mhHKY6hsECZyIzK6H?p=preview)

Your state definition could be simplified like this:

```
.state('home.first', {
    url: "/first",
    ...
.state('home.first.edit', {
    url: "/{firstId:[0-9]+}/edit",
    ...
.state('home.first.second', {
    url: "/second",
    ...
.state('home.first.second.edit', {
    url: "/{secondId:[0-9]+}/edit",
```

But the way you are expecting it to work should be like this:

```
.state('home.first', {
    url: "/first/{firstId:[0-9]+}",
    ...
.state('home.first.edit', {
    url: "/edit",
    ..
.state('home.first.second', {
    url: "/second/{secondId:[0-9]+}",
    ...
.state('home.first.second.edit', {
    url: "/edit",
```

These links will start to work then:

```
<a ui-sref="home.first({firstId:1})">
<a ui-sref="home.first({firstId:22})">
<a ui-sref="home.first.edit({firstId:333})">
<a ui-sref="home.first.edit({firstId:44444})">

<a ui-sref="home.first.second({firstId:4444})">
<a ui-sref="home.first.second.edit({firstId:1,secondId:333})">
<a ui-sref="home.first.second.edit({firstId:22,secondId:55555})">
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4O8mhHKY6hsECZyIzK6H?p=preview)

Comment: thanks. it working now. i was kept state parameters on parent state.